# Equivalent characterization of push-forward measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu, \nu$ be probability measure on the Polish spaces $X,Y$ respectively and $T:X\to Y$ measureable.
Prove that if $\forall f \in C_b(X)$
$$
\int_Y f(y) d\nu(y) = \int _X f(T(x)) d\mu (x)
$$
then $\nu$ is the pushforward measure of $\mu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E\subset Y$ be open, then you can presumably approximate $1_E$ monotonically by continuous bounded functions $(f_n)\uparrow 1_E$ (you can even just take $E$ to be a ball, then it should be easy to approximate $1_E$), then you have $$\nu(E)=\int 1_E d\nu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n d\nu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\circ T d\mu = \int 1_{T^{-1}(E)} d\mu = \mu(T^{-1}(E)),$$
where $f_n\circ T \uparrow 1_E\circ T = 1_{T^{-1}(E)}$. While the $f_n\circ T$ are not necessarily continuous anymore, they are still measurable, and they still converge monotonically in each point.

Since this equality holds on a set generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$, it
is true for the whole $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I am a bit concerned by the approximation part, this should be ok in $R^n$ but I would not know how to make it work in a general Polish space

Comment: If you have $E=B_r(x)$ then you can use Urysohn's Lemma to get a continuous function that is 1 on $\overline{B_{r-1/n}(x)}$ and 0 on the complement of $B_r(x)$.